# What does a 'good' approximation mean?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, motivation, linear-approximation

I am a graduate student and currently studying functions of several variables.I am mainly following *Paliogiannis and Moskowitz*.When they are introducing differentiability for function of several variables,they are drawing similarity with one variable differentiability.We say that $f:\Omega\subset \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ $(\Omega$ open$)$ is differentiable at $a\in \Omega$ if the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(a)$ exists (finitely).The same statement can be equivalently written as, $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{|f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)|}{|x-a|}=0$ which is equivalent to saying that $f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+o(|x-a|)$.Then they say that $f(x)\approx f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$ is a good approximation of $f(x)$ near $a$.They say that the numerator $|f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)|\to 0$ faster than the denominator $|x-a|\to 0$.I want to understand what is the significance of 'good approximation'?The error term goes to $0$ faster than $x\to a$,why is this being called 'good'?Can someone give me a little motivation?

Comment: I think the answer given by Paramanand Singh here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2577281/good-linear-approximation-criteria?rq=1 gives some insight.

Comment: There is no rigorous definition of "good" and what "good" is depends on the purpose of the approximation and which accuracy is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When derivative exists, we can say that $f(x)\approx f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$ in the sense that we can consider the following linear approximation

$$y(x)= f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$$

which is the tangent line for $f(x)$ at the point $x=a$.

[image]

This approximation is *good* in the sense that the difference

$$f(x)-y(x)=o(|x-a|)$$

as $x \to a$, goes to zero more rapidly than the linear quantity $|x-a|$ (or it is equal to zero when $f$ is linear).

By Taylor's series the concept can be generalized to obtain higher order polynomial approximation for $f(x)$ at a given point $x=a$.

For functions of two variables the linear approximation becomes a plane and also Taylor's series can be extended to several variables.

Refer also to the related

- [Derivative implies linear approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4266992/505767)